# Dynamically creating WHERE statements

Tags: php, codeigniter

The snippet below print out a query that fetches users from a DB who's DOB are in a certain age range. In this case, users that are either between 11 and 12 or 17 and 18 years old. I'm trying to dynamically create this query in CodeIgniter Active Record syntax.

This snippet

```
$age_count = 0;
foreach( $range as $r )
{
    $start_date = strtotime($r[0] . "years ago");
    $stop_date = strtotime($r[1] . "years ago");

    $range = array('dob <' => $start_date, 'dob >' => $stop_date);
    ( $age_count == "0" || $age_count%1 ) ? $this->db->where($range) : $this->db->or_where($range);

    $age_count++;
}
$users = $this->db->get("users")->result_array();
```

produces this query

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `dob` < 956351611 AND `dob` > 924729211 OR `dob` < 766962811 OR `dob` > 735426811
```

The last OR should of course be AND. How can I achieve this? It comes down to knowing when to use `or_where()` or simply `where()`. I thought every odd pass through the foreach should be an OR but I'm not quite there yet.

This function might just receive one range (11-12) or several ones.

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeignitor, but how about using a [between](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/100048/#508591)?

Comment: I could always use a "normal" query syntax should there not be solution ...

Comment: Actually I'd have the same problem when writing WHERE dob BETWEEN x AND y OR dob BETWEEN a AND B

Answer (score 0):

With the [database](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) API, you can use multiple `where()` to get a `WHERE … AND …`.

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('title', $title);
$this->db->where('status', $status); 

// WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

(tied from the documentation)

Comment: any explaination why -1 for, what seems to be a valid solution?